# For Junit issue: when test multiple thread

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, assert

I use JDK ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to do schdule job.  I give simple code as below.

```
 class Job implements  Callable<Void>{
         public Long id;

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            if (!isOk(id)) {
                return null;
            }

            _context.exe(id);
            return null;
        }


        void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

Every time i add this job to schedule service:

```
public void schedule() {
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setId(1L);;
    _scheduledExecutor.schedule(job, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) ;
}
```

this job will delay call context's exe method. 
My Question: I want assert _context's exe method called or not? How can I do this?

What I do currently, I try to add log in call() method and verify UT by my eyes.
PS: For this UT, I also try to mock _context's exe method, but job run in other thread, So I cannot assert it in currently thread. anyone have idea to help me write assert for this case?

Currently I do below way, but I still think there better solution for this, Just I don't known.

_context is instance of Context, I extend from this class.

```
public class UTContext extends Context {
public UTTestCase utTestCase ;

@Override
public void  exe(Long id) {
    utTestCase.setIsCall(true);  
}

public void setUtTestCase(UTTestCase utTestCase) {
    this.utTestCase = utTestCase;
}
```

}

Then I will assert isCall var in UT.

Is any one have good idea for this , pls give me answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: PS: What I try to do : create _context class extend existing _context and overwrite exit exe method, I will set this instance back to tested class when it created. and in this fake exe method I will write code to change my test case class's filed to notice is called or not . But I still think this bad way to test it. Any good idea for this . Thanks anyone who provide me ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing a piece of the middle of the call hierarchy, namely the thread creator/dispatcher code. That means you have to drive the code from the top and test either from the top or the bottom. There are several patterns for how you do that.

Either you instrument the bottom (`exe(id)`) or you measure from the top. With the scheduling delay, measuring from the top becomes very difficult.

Does `exe()` have side effects? Is that side effect testable from your test code? Can you infer the operation of one invocation of `exe()`? Can you infer the invocation of more than one? If the answer to any of these is "no", then you will have to go further.

@RamonBoza has provided a good solution.

You could also create a testable version of class `Job`, thus:

```
class JobUT extends Job {
  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception {
    Void result = super.call();
    // Report error if wrong return result
  }
}
```

(I know there are problems with the above code as `Void` is not being handled properly. I'm not in a position to refactor your code.)

You may also achieve the same objective using Aspect Oriented Programming, where you intercept the call after it has completed and perform the same testing.

Comment: Thanks for you bring so many good point to me.  The provided code is tailored. exe(id) method no other side effect,and I need mock this method, it's running complex env.. Overwrite the JOB class is good point, but the issue is that the job class is local variable in my source code. I cannot inject it when I ruining UT. 
May AspectJ can help on this but issue is that AspectJ jar not existing in currently project. our project have long process for apply new jar in source code. So can you have more detail for how to make "overwrite JOB class" work?

Comment: or you want me overwrite 'public void schedule()' at the same time. So I almost create 2 new class for this UT. is it good practice?

Comment: Not "Overwrite" -- "Override". By extending the class and overriding selected methods you are, in effect, opening the class for inspection but doing so without using introspection.

Comment: Yes, Override, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For asserting on multithreading I usually create 'N' threads, and assign a different value to set for each thread.

Then join them all and at the end just check if the data of each thread is ¿stored? for example.

Imagine, you create 1000 threads that stores an integer to a database, so after those 1000 threads has finished you have to check if in the database all the data is stored.

A more hard kind of test is for integration test and shall be perform with different scenarios and middleware (OpenNebula, Amazon cloud, etc).

Comment: My issue is we don't use any DB and I don't want change any source code for unit test. And you can see the Thread created in schedule method which I do not want to change, So cannot resolved my issue. My question is how write UT for this code without change exiting behavior.

Answer (score 0):

After server day, I know how to verify it now. I attached other question for reference:

[Assert times of expectLastCall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965745/assert-times-of-expectlastcall)

```
Service service = EasyMock.createMock(Service.class);
service.applyInitialDump(entities);
EasyMock.expectLastCall().times(100);

processor.processInitialDump(entities)
EasyMock.verify(service);
```